# Why are the standard datatypes not used in Win32 API?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, types

I have been learning Visual C++ Win32 programming for some time now.
Why are there the datatypes like `DWORD`, `WCHAR`, `UINT` etc. used instead of, say, `unsigned long`, `char`, `unsigned int` and so on?

I have to remember when to use WCHAR instead of const char *, and it is really annoying me.
Why aren't the standard datatypes used in the first place? Will it help if I memorize Win32 equivalents and use these for my own variables as well?

Comment: `WCHAR` is not the same as `char*`... (I get what you're asking though)

Comment: These are data types from Macro Assembler. That was the language in what Windows 1.0 was mostly written.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you should use the correct data-type for the arguments for functions, or you are likely to find yourself with trouble.

And the reason that these types are defined the way they are, rather than using `int`, `char` and so on is that it removes the "whatever the compiler thinks an `int` should be sized as" from the interface of the OS. Which is a very good thing, because if you use compiler A, or compiler B, or compiler C, they will all use the same types - only the library interface header file needs to do the right thing defining the types.

By defining types that are not standard types, it's easy to change `int` from 16 to 32 bit, for example. The first C/C++ compilers for Windows were using 16-bit integers. It was only in the mid to late 1990's that Windows got a 32-bit API, and up until that point, you were using `int` that was 16-bit. Imagine that you have a well-working program that uses several hundred `int` variables, and all of a sudden, you have to change ALL of those variables to something else... Wouldn't be very nice, right - especially as SOME of those variables DON'T need changing, because moving to a 32-bit int for some of your code won't make any difference, so no point in changing those bits.

It should be noted that `WCHAR` is NOT the same as `const char` - `WCHAR` is a "wide char" so `wchar_t` is the comparable type.

So, basically, the "define our own type" is a way to guarantee that it's possible to change the underlying compiler architecture, without having to change (much of the) source code. All larger projects that do machine-dependant coding does this sort of thing.

Comment: And `wchar_t` doesn't necessarily match `WCHAR` if you're using a non-Microsoft compiler.

Comment: I am in doubt… Why the GNU/Linux had not such a problem?

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Most likely because there was never a version of Linux for 16-bit processors. Note that most of this comes from the 1980's.

Comment: At first I thought that you was right, but next I saw that you're wrong. GNU/Linux could be run on every architecture that have MMU(and more, I saw an article where an enthusiast described in details how he managed to emulate MMU on some ancient CPU, and installed the linux kernel and minimal GNU utilities there, just for fun).

Comment: @Hi-Angel: MMU is not strictly needed - as long as the "mmu operations" are supported. However, I'm not aware of a true 16-bit version of Linux - when I say 16-bit, I mean one where `int` is a 16-bit value, rather than some other definition of "16-bit" processor. If you think you know of one, please let me know.

Answer (score 12):

The sizes and other characteristics of the built-in types such as `int` and `long` can vary from one compiler to another, usually depending on the underlying architecture of the system on which the code is running.

For example, on the 16-bit systems on which Windows was originally implemented, `int` was just 16 bits. On more modern systems, `int` is 32 bits.

Microsoft gets to define types like `DWORD` so that their sizes remain the same across different versions of their compiler, or of other compilers used to compile Windows code.

And the names are intended to reflect concepts on the underlying system, as defined by Microsoft. A `DWORD` is a "double word" (which, if I recall correctly, is 32 bits on Windows, even though a machine "word" is probably 32 or even 64 bits on modern systems).

It might have been better to use the fixed-width types defined in `<stdint.h>`, such as `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` -- but those were only introduced to the C language by the 1999 ISO C standard (which Microsoft's compiler doesn't fully support even today).

If you're writing code that interacts with the Win32 API, you should definitely use the types defined by that API.  For code that doesn't interact with Win32, use whatever types you like, or whatever types are suggested by the interface you're using.

Answer (score 11):

I think that it is a historical accident.

My theory is that the original Windows developers knew that the standard C type sizes depend on the compiler, that is, one compiler may have 16-bit integer and another a 32-bit integer. So they decided to make the Window API portable between different compilers using a series of typedefs: `DWORD` is a 32 bit unsigned integer, no matter what compiler/architecture you are using. Naturally, nowadays you will use `uint32_t` from `<stdint.h>`, but this wasn't available at that time.

Then, with the UNICODE thing, they got the `TCHAR` vs. `CHAR` vs. `WCHAR` issue, but that's another story.

And, then it grew out of control and you get such nice things as `typedef void VOID, *PVOID;` that are utterly nonsense.

Comment: +1 for PVOID nonsense :)

Comment: I'd venture a guess that things like PVOID are relics from the past dealing with near and far pointers.  Obviously it looks silly today, but people don't appreciate just how historical the Windows API is.