# Purpose of using Windows Data Types in a program

Tags: windows, types

I am trying to understand the purpose of using Windows Data Types when defining parameters of a function/structure fields in a particular language. I've read explanations detailing how this prevents code from "breaking" if "underlying types" are changed. Can some one present a concise explanation and example to clarify? Thanks.

Comment: If you're writing a Windows program and calling Windows API functions, they use Windows Data Types for parameters and return values, etc. Using Windows Data Types helps ensure that you're using the correct parameter/return types when interfacing with Windows API methods, functions, classes, etc.

Comment: Is it even possible to not use Windows Datatypes when calling windows API functions? For example if I am programming in Python, could I theoretically pass in Pythons datatypes to a Windows API function call?

Can you clarify what you mean by "correct parameter/return types"? What would be an incorrect parameter/return type? thanks

Comment: Yes you could if you tracked down what native type was represented by the WDT you were interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer in a similar post ([Why are the standard datatypes not used in Win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985229/why-are-the-standard-datatypes-not-used-in-win32-api)):

And the reason that these types are defined the way they are, rather than using int, char and so on is that it removes the "whatever the compiler thinks an int should be sized as" from the interface of the OS. Which is a very good thing, because if you use compiler A, or compiler B, or compiler C, they will all use the same types - only the library interface header file needs to do the right thing defining the types.

By defining types that are not standard types, it's easy to change int from 16 to 32 bit, for example. The first C/C++ compilers for Windows were using 16-bit integers. It was only in the mid to late 1990's that Windows got a 32-bit API, and up until that point, you were using int that was 16-bit. Imagine that you have a well-working program that uses several hundred int variables, and all of a sudden, you have to change ALL of those variables to something else... Wouldn't be very nice, right - especially as SOME of those variables DON'T need changing, because moving to a 32-bit int for some of your code won't make any difference, so no point in changing those bits.

It should be noted that WCHAR is NOT the same as const char - WCHAR is a "wide char" so wchar_t is the comparable type.

So, basically, the "define our own type" is a way to guarantee that it's possible to change the underlying compiler architecture, without having to change (much of the) source code. All larger projects that do machine-dependant coding does this sort of thing.

Comment: Still one question: If the windows data types themselves are changed by Microsoft, wouldn't this cause the exact same problem of having to go back through and change hundreds of compiler specific variables?